# How to convert each() to something supported

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to clean up warnings in some old PHP code, specifically this code:

```
function & XML_serialize(&$data, $level = 0, $prior_key = NULL){
    #assumes a hash, keys are the variable names
    $xml_serialized_string = "";
    while(list($key, $value) = each($data)){
        $inline = false;
        $numeric_array = false;
        $attributes = "";
        #echo "My current key is '$key', called with prior key '$prior_key'<br>";

        if(!strstr($key, " attr")){ #if it's not an attribute
            if(array_key_exists("$key attr", $data)){
                while(list($attr_name, $attr_value) = each($data["$key attr"])){
                    #echo "Found attribute $attribute_name with value $attribute_value<br>";
                    $attr_value = &htmlspecialchars($attr_value, ENT_QUOTES);
                    $attributes .= " $attr_name=\"$attr_value\"";
                }
            }

            if(is_numeric($key)){
                #echo "My current key ($key) is numeric. My parent key is '$prior_key'<br>";
                $key = $prior_key;
            }else{
                #you can't have numeric keys at two levels in a row, so this is ok
                #echo "Checking to see if a numeric key exists in data.";
                if(is_array($value) and array_key_exists(0, $value)){
                    # echo " It does! Calling myself as a result of a numeric array.<br>";
                    $numeric_array = true;
                    $xml_serialized_string .= XML_serialize($value, $level, $key);
                }
                #echo "<br>";
            }
            if(!$numeric_array){
                $xml_serialized_string .= str_repeat("\t", $level) . "<$key$attributes>";
                if(is_array($value)){
                   $xml_serialized_string .= "\r\n" . XML_serialize($value, $level+1);
                }else{
                    $inline = true;
                    $xml_serialized_string .= htmlspecialchars($value);
                }
                $xml_serialized_string .= (!$inline ? str_repeat("\t", $level) : "") . "</$key>\r\n";
            }
        }else{
            #echo "Skipping attribute record for key $key<bR>";
        }
    }
    if($level == 0){
        $xml_serialized_string = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\r\n" . $xml_serialized_string;
        return $xml_serialized_string;
    }else{
        return $xml_serialized_string;
    }
}
```

I tried to replace `while(list($key, $value) = each($data))` with `foreach($data as $key => $value)` but it does not return the expected results.

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php?